# using global variable in other functions in matlab

Tags: matlab

I declared few global variables(x, y, id...) in a MATLAB function named 'node'. Now I want to use the values obtained in 'node' in some other MATLAB function. Should I define the global variables again whenever I want to use them or can I just use them as we use a global variable in 'c'?

Comment: Also, don't use global variables. Pass the values obtained in one function as arguments to your other functions.

Comment: thanks, but I have like some 10 functions and a main script file where I need to use the same variables and all the variables are either one or two dimensional array and in some functions I'll be using only some particular values of a vector so I don't want to pass the complete vector as argument every time. I'm not sure if I'm writing my code the right way. I mostly write code in C.

Comment: If you know which particular values you need in the function, you can pass only those along as arguments when calling the function.

Comment: Using global variables is considered bad programming, it leads to unexpected errors and headaches while debugging, plus your code is obscure because you dontk know which function uses what variables. Try to avoid them as much as you can

Comment: The problem is I don't always know which particular value I have to use at every step. That's why I declared global variables so I can just use the values whichever needed.

Comment: That doesn't make it not bad programming. If you have variables that are consistently used in subfunctions consider utilizing a [structure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) so you only need to pass one variable. And consider programming in a way where your code isn't obscure to yourself, because it's certainly going to be obscure to others. Globals are not the answer.